# How to save string as objects in the database by Vue.js?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, vue.js, object

I am creatingan app in Vue.js, Node.js and MongoDB.
First, I get data from user in texarea, for example this data:

```
            "actions": {
                "replace":
                {
                    "frontend": [
                        {
                            "search": "aaa",
                            "replace": "bbb"
                        },
                    ],
                    "backend": []

                }
            }
        }
```

Then I convert it into a JSON object and send it to the backend:

```
      const json = JSON.stringify(this.data);
      this.data = JSON.parse(json);
```

But it is saved in the database as a long string, instead of objects. How to fix it?

Comment: The probjem is specific to back end and not Vue. This wasn't shown. You need to parse JSON on server side, and you likely don't do that.

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the `      const json = JSON.stringify(this.data);
` line

Comment: @RCvaram Then there is an error with the type

Comment: @Estus Flask I just did it on server side, but it's still save as a string

Comment: This isn't confirmed that you did this correctly because you didn't post the relevant code. Currently only you can debug what happens. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You need to narrow down the problem to either front or back end. You can clearly see what's transmitted in browser devtools.